# Multiple Pictures in bytes

Tags: python, flask, bytesio

i am trying to save multiple Pictures in one Bytes object from BytesIO. And later on acces these Pictures again from bytes to Picture. But i certainly don't know much about bytes. Is there a way to put something after one Picture in to the Buffer that it later knows where the Picture ends?
Client Side:

```
#cv2 Capture Frame
ret, frame = cls.__cap.read()
buf = BytesIO()
for i in range(10):
    Image.fromarray(frame).save(buf, format='JPEG')
    # Here the Logic for differentiating Pictures
body = buf.getvalue()
requests.post(url,data=body,headers={'content-type': 'application/x-image'})
```

Website Side:

```
images_as_bytes = BytesIO(flask.request.data)
for i in range(10):
    # Here the Logic for differentiating Pictures
    img = Image.open(images_as_bytes)
    frame = np.asarray(img)
    # process
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the rationale or validity of what you are doing, but you could maybe leverage the fact that all JPEGs end with the `EOI` marker which is:

```
0xff 0xd9
```

And they start with the `SOI` marker which is:

```
0xff 0xd8
```

Similarly, PNG images begin with:

```
0x89 0x50 0x4e 0x47 0x0d 0x0a 0x1a 0x0a
```

and end with:

```
0x49 0x45 0x4e 0x44 0xae 0x42 0x60 0x82
```

---

Here is some completely untested, somewhat related code to give you an idea of how to split 2 concatenated PNG images:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import mmap
import re

pattern = re.compile(rb'(\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a.*?\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xAE\x42\x60\x82)', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

# I guess we could do 2 TIFFs just as easily, or JPEGs
with open('TwoConcatenatedPNGs.png', 'rb') as f:
    with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0,
                   access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as m:
        i = pattern.finditer(m)
        for p in i:
         print(p.span())
```

Create the test file like this:

```
cat IMAGE1.PNG IMAGE2.PNG > TwoConcatenatedPNGs.png
```

Best links for understanding Python [regex](https://pymotw.com/3/re/index.html) and [mmap](https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer i am basically capturing frames from a Camera Source and then send them out to a Cloud Service and i want to limit the number of requests with not sending one request with one frame, sending one request with lets say 20 Images. Then Process them and send them back. Do you maybe have a basic example of how to implement your answer in code. Or also know a better way to do this?

Comment: I haven't got time at the moment to do that and test it, but I'll add some code I have lying around on my Mac that uses regexes to search for PNG markers so you get an idea. I'll edit it into my question - it is not 100% commented or tested - it is conceptual... *caveat emptor* !